# Initialize a variable and access it after changing its value in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to translate this Objective-C code into Swift:

```
- (void) performActivity{
NSMutableString *reversedStrings = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *string in self.activityItems){
    [reversedStrings appendString:[self reverseOfString:string]];
    [reversedStrings appendString:@"\n"];
}
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reversed"
                                                    message:reversedStrings
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

}

My Swift code is:

```
override func performActivity() {

    var reversedStrings = String()

    for string in activityItems{

        reversedStrings += reverseOfString(string)
        reversedStrings += "\n"
    }

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Reversed",
        message: reversedStrings,
        delegate: self,
        cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel",
        otherButtonTitles: "Ok")

    alert.show()
}
```

but the message in my alert is still the empty string. How can I access the reversedStrings, which is the result of the for loop? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I presume `reverseOfString` is a class method developed by you. Probably the error is in there - can you post its implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your implementation of `reverseOfString()` doesn't work correctly. Here is a working solution:

```
var reversedStrings = String()

for string in activityItems{

    reversedStrings += string.reverse()
    reversedStrings += "\n"
}
```

which uses a `String` extension implementing a `reverse` method:

```
extension String {
    func reverse() -> String {
        var result = ""

        for character in self {
            result = "\(character)" + result
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: @Catfish_Man: that's true, but it returns an array of characters, so you still have to join them